# Copy offset range in for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that loops through a list of ID numbers to check if there is a matching ID in another list, if there is a matching ID, it copies the email in the adjacent column and pastes it in another range. I am having trouble copying an offset range since it doesn't appear to be pasting any values. This script is not throwing any errors:

```
Sub tryThis()

Dim lookHere As Range, pasteHere As Range, cell As Range, searchList As Range

Set List1 = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
Set List2 = Range(Range("C1"), Range("C1").End(xlDown))
    
For Each cell In List1
    
    Set found = List2.Find(what:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        
        cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 1).Copy Destination:=Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)
    
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the email to be copied from List1 or List 2?

Comment: From the cell NEXT to List 2

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 1).Copy _
      Destination:=Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)
```

will copy the value into the same cell each run, since `End(xlUp)` takes you to the last *occupied* cell in the column, not the first empty cell.  You need to `Offset()` one down to the next empty position.  Also can do this with a direct value assignment:

```
Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

Edit: if the cell you want to copy is from List 2 then:

```
Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = found.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

Comment: Thanks. The cell I need to copy is the cell beside List 2, since it's an email in the adjacent column